# custom ShapeBorder in flutter stuck on top -> SOLVED

Tags: flutter, containers, shapes

I've created a ShapeBorder for a Container, but when I use the shape is painted on the top of the screen

[image]

As seen in the image, the blank spot between the 2 containers (green & blue) is where the red shape should be,

This is my shape:

```
 class BottomButtonShape extends ShapeBorder {
 @override
 EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.only();

 @override
 ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;

 @override
 Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}){
  Path path = Path();
 return Path();
 }

@override
Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {

Path path = Path();
path.lineTo(rect.width, rect.height);
path.lineTo(20, rect.height);
path.lineTo(20, 0);
path.lineTo(0,0 );

return path;
}

@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? 
textDirection}) {
 }
 }
```

And the Container is:

```
Container(
          height: 100,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
              shape: BottomButtonShape(),
              shadows: [BoxShadow(color: AppColors.black, blurRadius: 20)],
              color: Colors.red
          ),
        ),
```

EDIT SOLUTION:
I realized that the issue was that the rect inside the Shape has to be relative to the rect.top & rect.bottom, so, the left corner would be rect.left,rect.top and any shape from there would be rect.top+number and so on

Comment: this is because you do `path.lineTo(0,0);`

Comment: @pskink Yep, i though i was drawing inside then Container, but them how I do paint on the container spot? Relative to what?

Comment: Ok, I realized that the rect has a side property (top, bottom, left, right) that is the position. Thanks @pskink , it helped me realize the solution